# Jpa repository returns null value in specific package

Tags: java, jpa, repository

Currently I can access `repository` method in `JUnit` test class method. But the same repository method if I access this method in a different package then the repository method returns `null` value.

Repository method return value in the Junit test method.

Repository method return null value in the following package com.bancaeSub.util;

please advise. Thanks.

### Coding:

`ComQuoteMRepository`:

```
package com.bancaeSub.repository;

@Repository
public interface ComQuoteMRepository extends JpaRepository<ComQuoteM,String>{
    ComQuoteM findByQuotationNo(String quotationNo);    
}
```

And `MainApplication`:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories
@EnableTransactionManagement
@Configuration
public class MainApplication {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    ComClientProfileRepository comClientProfileRepository;  

    @Autowired
    ComClientProfileAgentLinkList comClientProfileAgentLinkListRepository;

    static Properties getProperties() {
        Properties props = new Properties();        
        props.put("spring.config.name", "application");
        return props;

    }                                       
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication app =new SpringApplication();
        app.setDefaultProperties(getProperties());
        app.run(MainApplication.class, args);                      
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you `@Autowired` `ComQuoteMRepository` in `com.allianz.bancaeSub.util` package?

Comment: Yes it was already @Autowired in the util package.

Comment: Any advise? Thanks.

Comment: I think Spring is unable to scan `com.allianz.bancaeSub.util` package correctly. Try specifying this package in `@ComponentScan` annotation.

Comment: As per the advise i added the @ComponentScan in corresponding class. It shows the same error.